Override spill cell
Is there a way to override spill cells without getting an error? Lets say in the A column I the cells contain some numbers in B1 I have "=A1:A10". Now I want to have a different value that I set only in B7. How can I override the value of this cell without getting a spill error?
Example:


You can't. In e.g. C1 you could use something like =IF(B1:B10="",A1:A10,B1:B10).

@VBasic2008 okay technically you're correct, but there are lots of ways to get what OP screenshot to have the desired result. However, I updated my answer to reflect your accurate statement :☺

@pgSystemTester For accuracy's sake, I would argue that the 'VBA word' empty has no room in 'Excel Formula'. The 'Excel word' is blank, AFAIK, exclusively, sometimes misleadingly, used in the Excel documentation. Hardly related but as a reminder, =ISBLANK(cell) checks if a cell is blank and =COUNTA(range)=0 if a range is blank. In a function description, the phrase "cells containing nothing" was used for cells that appear blank but are not e.g. ="", '... and the same ones copied as values. =COUNTBLANK(range) returns the sum of the number of those and blank cells.

A SpillRange will only spill if the entire range it's expanding to is empty -- no way around this. However, there are lots of ways to accomplish the same functional result by adjusting the formula to behave differently in that particular cell.
Here's a few ideas:
=IF(ROW(A1:A10)=7,"Something Else",A1:A10)`

I prefer to use the LET function to reduce the number of address references in a formula, even if it makes it longer, so I'd use:
=LET(zRange,A1:A10,IF(ROW(zRange)=7,"Let version Something Else",zRange))`

Overall something like Map Function seems  most useful. I like including helper arrays as this:
=LET(keyRng, A1:A10, iRng, SEQUENCE(ROWS(keyRng),1),gResult,
    MAP(keyRng,iRng, LAMBDA(kVal,iVal,IF(iVal=7,"oh NO!!", iVal))),gResult)



The following will override and feed into multiple cells, however the solution posted above by Steven Sir, should work for your context in the OP, but here is another alternative:

=LET(α, A1:A10, IFERROR(MAP(IFNA(XMATCH(ROW(α),D2:D4),""),LAMBDA(r, CHOOSEROWS(E2:E4,r))),α))


Another alternative way could be using either VLOOKUP() or XLOOKUP()
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A10,D2:E4,2,0),A1:A10)



Couple of more variants, for fun:
=LAMBDA(src,
    IFS(
        src = 9,
        90,
        src = 3,
        30,
        TRUE,
        src
    )
)(A1:A10)

or
=LAMBDA(src,
    IFNA(
        XLOOKUP(
            src,
            {3, 9},
            {30, 90}
        ),
        src
    )
)(A1:A10)


